# Windows services connecting to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-services, sql-server-2016

I have a Windows service running in the server. When the clients in the domain connect to the service, it is able to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 / SQL Server 2012 / SQL Server 2016. However, when the Windows service is accessed over the internet, it fails to connect to the SQL Server.

Service runs as Network Service and SQL Server has login rights Network Service. Otherwise even domain client accessing windows services will not be able to access.

It was working properly i.e connecting SQL Server when I used in the Windows service `OLEDbConnection` to access SQL Server. I changed to `DBConnection` as we want to support MySQL as well in addition to SQL Server, DB2 and Oracle. After changing to `DBconnection`, I have encountered this issue.

The error message is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: I was able to find a workaround. In the OleDBConnection Version of Windows service, if the Data source is specified as Server Name it is translated to IP address and the SQL server instance is accessed. But in the DBconnection version of the service this translation does not take place. But if the IP address is given, it access without any problem. Can somebody tell me what should  be done so that DBconnection Version can use Server name instead of IP address for elegancy